# simplest way to load android webview

Tags: android

what is the simplest way to load android webview?

I have already specified webview in the activity layout, how can i load a website on it while running the emulator. I have had many problems with resources not identified and the main_activity.out.xml files have been giving me troubles. A simple webview to load a webpage would be nice.

...

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting `main_activity.out.xml` because you are trying to compile Xml files (main_activity.out.xml have the focus and you clicked run). In general if this error happens you have to

1. Delete the xxx.out.xml
2. Open any .java file in src/ by double click in the file so it has focus and the cursor is in there
3. Run your project and everything should be OK now

to load WebView you have to declare your webview component in your xml

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/myWebView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

and then in your activity in onCreate() method call

```
// get reference to your view
WebView webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
// load your WebView content
webview.loadUrl("http://google.com/");
```

Comment: i get 
 
it gave me the following error Multiple markers at this line - Cannot cast from View to WebView - Line breakpoint:WebView [line: 16] - onCreate(Bundle) before compiling

Comment: public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_view);
        WebView webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        webview.loadUrl("http://stackoverflow.com/");
        // this is line 16
    }

Comment: @LeTruffle clean your project and let me know if the error persist

Comment: WebView webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);

Comment: @LeTruffle you have used your xml declaration or mine?

Comment: they are the same:  
    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13511/discussion-between-k-anas-and-letruffle)

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way?

Get access to WebView via

```
WebView webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
webview.loadUrl("http://stackoverflow.com/");
```

Greets
Flo

Comment: it gave me the following error Multiple markers at this line
 - Cannot cast from View to WebView
 - Line breakpoint:WebView [line: 16] - 
  onCreate(Bundle)

Comment: Why downvote? Im sure this code works simply because i use it exact this way... How about casting to WebView? Have you forgotten the (WebView) part in front of findViewById?

Answer (score 0):

main_activity.out.xml has been created maybe beacuse you pressed the run button on Eclipse while your main_activity.xml was opened. Eclipse tryed to compile your xml and not your application.

To do that right, try to select the reference of your application inside the project explorer on the left and then click the Run button.

In order to manage at best the webview in your android project, just read the documentation:

http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html